# shuffle a python array WITH replacement

Tags: python, arrays, list, shuffle

What is the easiest way to shuffle a python array or list WITH replacement??

I know about `random.shuffle()` but it does the reshuffling WITHOUT replacement.

Comment: You mean repeated `random.choice()` calls?

Comment: ohh yes, i can do it with random.choice().. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`random.choice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) calls in a list comprehension:

```
[random.choice(lst) for _ in range(len(lst))]
```

This produces a list of the same length as the input list, but the values can repeat.

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> lst = [1,2,4,5,3]
>>> [random.choice(lst) for _ in range(len(lst))]
[3, 5, 1, 4, 1]
```

Comment: yes, this is perfect.. :) thank you for such a quick response

Comment: This is not the same operation as shuffling. As you can see in the example, the input list and output list do not have the same elements.

Comment: @bheklilr: No, it is not the same operation, *that is the point*. Otherwise `random.shuffle()` would have fit the requirements.

Comment: @bheklilr: the OP described it poorly, but this gives you a random list of values from the original list, allowing for replacemets.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand now, he wanted combination, not permutation, of the list, but I assumed that he wanted a permutation without modifying the original list.